# php - remove characters after periods for multiple items in multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have an object called $dbs which contains multiple arrays with multiple items in them. I'm trying to remove the characters after the periods of each item.

PHP

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($dbs);
print "</pre>";
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [1] => FMServer_Sample.fmp12
)
Array
(
    [1] => GolfAudit4.fmp12
    [2] => iCDS.fmp12
    [3] => rawhide.fmp12
)
Array
(
    [1] => Assets.fmp12
    [2] => PassTracker.fmp12
    [3] => Scanner.fmp12
)
Array
(
    [1] => prima.fmp12
)
Array
(
    [1] => CNAC_db.fmp12
)
```

When I do something like...

```
$db = array();
foreach ($dbs as $db) {
     $db = substr($db, 0, (strlen($db)) - (strlen(strrchr($db, '.'))));
     print "<pre>";
     print_r($db);
     print "</pre>";
}
```

I'm able to remove the characters after the periods, but I can only return the items from each array while in the foreach loop. When I print_r() $db outside of the loop I can only return the first item from each array. What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to put each item from each array into a new array that I can use outside of the loop?

Comment: have you tried using reference? `&` on `foreach ($dbs as &$db)`?

Comment: Your output should not be just one variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting your array everytime it loops, try changing tour code to:

```
 <?php
 $dbNew = array();
 foreach ($dbs as $db) {
       $dbNew[] = substr($db, 0, (strlen($db)) - (strlen(strrchr($db, '.'))));
 }
 print "<pre>";
 print_r($dbNew);
 print "</pre>";
 ?>
```

Comment: is it possible to put the items from each array into a new array, possibly as strings?

Comment: I don't understand what you want, can you provide the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) to create a new array instead:

```
$dbs = array_map(function($db) {
    return strtok($db, '.'); // only use first portion
}, $dbs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<?php 
$dbs = array(array(1 => 'FMServer_Sample.fmp12'), array(1 => 'GolfAudit4.fmp12', 2 => 'iCDS.fmp12', 3 => 'rawhide.fmp12'), array (1 => 'Assets.fmp12', 2 => 'PassTracker.fmp12', 3 => 'Scanner.fmp12'), array(1 => 'prima.fmp12'), array(1 => 'CNAC_db.fmp12'));

$arrNewDb = array();
foreach ($dbs as $db) {
   foreach ($db as $val) {
     $arrDb = explode(".", $val);
     $arrNewDb[] = $arrDb[0];
   }
}

print "<pre>";
print_r($arrNewDb);
print "</pre>";
?>
```